# Prototype Functions C++

Tags: c++, function-prototypes, xcode8.2

I am having build errors when declaring prototype functions within Xcode. I am writing in C++. The script is pulled from my professor's lecture. Attached below is a picture of the build errors, along with the script itself.
Note: I only run into build issues when trying to declare prototype functions. It is as if Xcode is trying to pull the functions from a Library, and not recognizing it.

```
Code: 
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int calcSquare (int num) ;

int main ()
{

    int num = 5;

    int result;

    result = calcSquare(num);

    cout << "The Square of " << num << " is " <<  result << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Errors: https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2871/33406384892_68ee0843c7_b.jpg

Comment: You must define your function in any cpp file within your project.

Comment: Before you get into the habit, try to avoid `using namespace std` and instead embrace the `std::` prefix. It's there to provide separation.

Comment: You know you have to actually write the function, right?

Comment: Okay so I just included the function definition just above "int main()" and the build succeeded. Thank you @Michael Nastenko, immibis. tadman I am very new to programming, any suggestions as far as references go regarding the "std:: prefix", and any and all CPP Documentation is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your program is that you forgot to DEFINE the function prototype later in your source code. 
Right now, you simply have a function prototype ( int calcSquare ), but you called that function anyways.

That throws you the linker exception as shown.

In other words, define the function somewhere in your source code to use the `<cmath>, <cctype>, <cstdlib>` modules and libraries.

After the function prototype, declare the function later:

```
int calcSquare (int num) {
   ...
}
```

I hope this helps! :)